# Display h:message when h:commandButton invoked

Tags: jsf

I have a `password recovery` form in jsf:

```
<h:form id="arForm">
    <p:panel id="arp">
        <p:focus context="arp"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="...">

            <h:message id="emailMsg" for="email"/>
            <h:inputText id="email" value="#{accountBean.email}" required="true" label="email">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="..."/>
                <f:ajax event="blur" render="emailMsg"/>
            </h:inputText>
            <p:watermark for="email" value="Enter email address..."/>

            <h:commandButton id="recoverBtn" value="Recovery" action="#{accountBean.sendEmail()}" class="recoverBtn">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:messages id="emailResult" globalOnly="true" showDetail="true"/>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

And this is `accountBean.sendEmail()`:

```
public void sendEmail() throws Exception {
    boolean sendResult = false;
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("arForm:emailMsg", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "", "Please Wait... "));

    sendResult = sendHtmlEmail(...to entered email);

    if (sendResult) {
         // emailResult message that says there is an internal problem
    } else {
        // emailResult message that says there is an internal problem
    }
}
```

I want when user entered email and clicked on `Recovery` button, the `Please Wait...` message appears until the email sent and it's corresponding message appears.

But problem is that the `Please Wait...` message not displayed at all.

Comment: You are looking for a wrong approach. Use either [`<p:blockUI>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml) or [`<pe:blockUI>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/blockui/blockUIAjax.jsf) instead. There is also a [`<p:ajaxStatus>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml). Everything is of course dependent upon the project's requirement.

Comment: `<p:watermark>` (or `<p:panel>`, `<p:focus>`) is a witness of PrimeFaces usage in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On contrary to what you seemed to expect, the view won't be rendered until the action method returns.

You need to show that message in the client side during DOM `click` event. JavaScript is helpful in this.

Basically:

```
<h:form>
    <span id="pleaseWait" style="display:none">Please wait ...</span>
    ...
    <h:commandButton ... onclick="$('#pleaseWait').show()">
        <f:ajax ... render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

(obviously with inline CSS/JS refactored out in real code)

Comment: But it not displayed !

Comment: My `commandButton` is in `panel Grid`, should be out of that?

Comment: No. Apparently you changed the code in the question/answer without me knowing that. This snippet works for me and anyone else when copypasted in a blank playground project.

Comment: My last edit is `10 hours ago` , I copypasted your code and remove `...` characters and when i clicked to button, the message not appeared.

Comment: Note that my code assumes that you're using PrimeFaces in same page (exactly as in your initial question). If you're seeing a JS error in browser's JS console like `$ is undefined`, then you apparently don't have a PrimeFaces widget component in your page. In that case, you'd need to replace jQuery code by Vanilla JS like so `onclick="document.getElementById('pleaseWait').style.display='block'"`, or to explicitly import PrimeFaces-bundled jQuery.